# Pass an object to Service handler callback() function

Tags: ros, python

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

is there a way to pass objects to a callback()? I just found this post:
https://answers.ros.org/question/231492/passing-arguments-to-callback-in-python/

but if I pass the object like mentioned in the post I get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/rospy/impl/tcpros_base.py", line 737, in receive_once
    self.stat_bytes += recv_buff(sock, b, p.buff_size)
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/rospy/impl/tcpros_base.py", line 104, in recv_buff
    d = sock.recv(buff_size)
TypeError: 'AiService' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/rospy/impl/tcpros_service.py", line 667, in handle
    requests = transport.receive_once()
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/rospy/impl/tcpros_base.py", line 758, in receive_once
    raise TransportException("receive_once[%s]: unexpected error %s"%(self.name, str(e)))
rospy.exceptions.TransportException: receive_once[/image_ack]: unexpected error 'AiService' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

My code (shortened):

```
def callback(request, arg):
    response = ImageAckResponse()
    ai_machine = arg[0]
    ...
    return response

def main():
    rospy.init_node('ai_service')
    ai_machine = AiMachine()
    ...
    rospy.Service('image_ack', ImageAck, callback, (ai_machine))
    rospy.spin()
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/379966/pass-an-object-to-service-handler-callback()-function/) by [TELESPIELSTUBE](https://answers.ros.org/users/75120/telespielstube/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2021-06-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-06-09**:
Is `service` already a `tuple`? If not, you must enclose it in `()`. Otherwise you cannot unpack it in your callback.

**Comment by [TELESPIELSTUBE](https://answers.ros.org/users/75120/telespielstube/) on 2021-06-09**:
Changed the object name to `ai_machine` for better understanding and enclosed the object but still getting the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not sure whether anything has changed in `rospy` in the meantime, but I believe the problem is that `rospy.Service(..)` does not support that additional args argument described in the Q&A you link. That's for `rospy.Subscriber(..)` only.

See #q247540 for a potential work-around, using a lambda.

Another option would be to create a class, and make `callback(..)` a method on that class. It could then refer to any member variables of that class.

The reason you get that error ("") is because `rospy.Service(..)` expects a `buff_size` argument (an `integer`) where you are passing your `AiMachine` instance. See [the documentation](http://docs.ros.org/en/melodic/api/rospy/html/rospy.impl.tcpros_service.Service-class.html):

> ```
> __init__(self, name, service_class, handler, buff_size=65536, error_handler=None)
> ```

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-06-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1